# How to read in Hebrew letters in Visual Studios C++

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, visual-studio-2017, hebrew

I'm trying to read in a Hebrew text file, do some modifications, then send it to another text file. I've been successful in displaying Hebrew letters using UTF8, but I can't seem to read them in. This code successfully prints out the Hebrew letters to the txt file that it was redirected to, but when I try to read in Hebrew from another text file (that was redirected in) I get random garbage. How do I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
    wprintf(L"\x05D0");//works with courier new in terminal
    wchar_t example[] = L"א";
    wcout << endl << example << endl;
    wstring x;
    getline(wcin, x);
    wcout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
א
א
ï»¿×××× ×©×××ª ×× × ××©×¨×× ××××× ××¦×¨××× ××ª ××¢×§× ×××© ××××ª× ××× â¬
```

Comment: What is the format of the text file?  Is it utf 8, utf 16 ucs 2?  Or a windows specific hebrew mbcs codepage?

Comment: Your examples are **not** UTF8 strings. They are wide characters. To make `example` an utf8 string, change it to `char_t example[] = u8"א";`.

Comment: Change `_O_U8TEXT` to `_O_U16TEXT` Repeat for `stdin` -> `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been figured out. It was what Barmak Shemirani said almost. I put in _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT); and changed my output to U16 and then still got garbage then I changed them both to U8 and I was able to read in and out perfectly.